# Jenkins job notification fails with "No git consumers for URI ..."

Tags: git, curl, jenkins

I want to set up a `post-receive` `git` hook that notify `jenkins` about the change, but no job is triggered in `jenkins`.

My `post-receive` hook looks like this:

```
curl http://localhost/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<git_repository_url>
```

If I issue the command in terminal, I get the following message:

```
"No git consumers for URI..."
```

I have a jenkins job that connected to Git Source Code Management, repository URL is given as well as branches: `*/master`

I've searched for this problem, but I've found nothing useful related to: "No git consumers for URI"

I use:

- LinuxMint
- Apache 2.4.6
- git 1.8.3.2
- curl 7.32.0
- Jenkins 1.532.2

I have a proxy setup in apache:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
   allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
```

The git repository is `bare`.

Answer (score 44):

Enable SCM polling for each project you want to notify:

1. Go to the **Dashboard**.
2. Click on your **project**.
3. Click **Configure**.
4. Under *Build Triggers* check the box for **Poll SCM**.
5. Repeat for any other projects.

The notification you send tells Jenkins to poll the repository, so projects will only respond if SCM polling is enabled.

Comment: followed this answer, and see the following messages 
"Scheduled polling of jenkins_test
No git consumers for URI git@xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx.git"
it works now, thanks!

Comment: Nice note: you can leave out the `Schedule` portion so that it never runs unless the hook is triggered. This does appear to work even though the message says it will never run.

Comment: In addition to the above I also found that the repo URL set in Jenkins had to be a lower case even though in bitbuckect some of the characters were uppercase.

Answer (score 16):

The message `No git consumers for URI` always shows up, you should be worried if you see `No git jobs using repository`. The response will contain a list of jobs scheduled for polling, so as long as you see them, the polling was triggered.

That said you might want to check that polling is actually *doing* something. If you go into a job configured with Git, you can see a link to the Git Polling Log on the left. In there you'll be able to see if the trigger actually did anything and, more crucially, if there was an error.

I had an issue similar to this, and it took me a while to figure out that my Git was misconfigured. My job will build fine when manually triggered, but the polling trigger would use a different path to the Git binary and fail. I ended up having to define the Git path to fix my issue.

Comment: thanks. indeed. Nothing wrong, but I searched for the problem for an hour °-.-

Answer (score 7):

I had to take the following steps:

1. Enable **SCM Polling** as answered by @angstadt530

   - project->configure->"Build Triggers"->"Enable SCM Polling" ... check it
2. Check the **Git Polling Log** as answered by @monitorjbl

   - project->"Git Polling Log" ... to identify #3
3. **Force polling using workspace**

   - project->configure->"Source Code Management"->"Additional Behaviors"->add->"Force polling using workspace" ... select it from the pulldown.

After completing #1 in addition to "No git consumers for URI gitRepoURI" I also got, "Scheduled Polling of projectName".

However, looking at the Git Polling Log I found the error message: **Can not run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe": error=2, No such file or directory**

To fix this error I had to configure source code management to Force polling using workspace (#3). I'm not sure why, because manually initiated builds work fine.  Maybe a bug -- maybe the mixing of a linux server and a windows slave.  But either way, this finally fixed it for me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @djh It also worked for me in case or Azure Repo(SCM) --> Jenkins(build Server). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to solution of @idontevenseethecode

Don't forget to check "Repository URL" under "Source Code Management" if the git repo is the dedicated one!