# Trigger Jenkins build from Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

How to trigger `Jenkins` build from pushing to `Github` master branch? I figured out one generally does that by `git hook` which connects to build trigger url. I tried with local git repository and got the following error message:

```
No git jobs using repository: file:///home/*****/workspace/testz and branches: 
No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: file:///home/*****/workspace/testz
```

Then I decided to try trigger the hook from Github, but I couldn't figure out how to configure hooks on Github.

Comment: Byt using the Git plugin you can also configure you job to poll the SCM at certain intervals. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins job notification fails with "No git consumers for URI ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000199/jenkins-job-notification-fails-with-no-git-consumers-for-uri)

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because it won't answer your question, but I want to recommend something I've implemented in my build system called Verigreen - https://github.com/Verigreen/verigreen/wiki - Take a quick look and if you're open to cool open source projects it might just be the answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to configure your job to pull the SCM at certain intervals.

[image]
  [image]

1. Choose type of VCS to use.
2. Enter repository to pull from.
3. Enter your credentials to access the repository.
4. You may specify which branch to checkout.
5. You can also add additionals behaviors, like specifying to checkout into a specific directory, etc.
6. You can configure to trigger the builds from scripts.
7. You can also configure it to poll the SCM at certain intervals.

Comment: This is a bad solution as it's not really continuous integration, where build should be driven by commits and not by polling, which is inefficient and may theoretically cause problems with timing.

Comment: The question was how to trigger builds from github and I think this is a working solution. Furthermore nothing will be built unless there is a new commit on the specified branch. My guess is that you don't see jenkins as a CI solution at all?